# How this MX toolbox Blacklist Checking Works?

Tags: blacklist

I wonder how this blacklist checking works for MxtoolBOX. Is there any general methods to check IP address for a blacklist in servers . What principle they used ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically they use reverse dns lookups against 100+ dns server which do the black listing.
Another [nice site](http://www.blacklistbox.com) to check if your server is blacklisted it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple DNS query.

Example.

To check IP address 1.2.3.4 if it exists in blacklist like zen.spamhaus.org then

you should reverse the ip to be 4.3.2.1 and perform the query like 4.3.2.1.zen.spamhaus.org

If the result is 127.0.0.2 then this IP is a spam source else it's not a spam source.

this is the same concept as adminkit blacklist check
http://www.adminkit.net/dnsbl.aspx